# Start a VMWare guest on the second monitor automatically?

Tags: multiple-monitors, vmware, automation

I'm trying to automate some daily chores, one of them starting a virtual machine on my secondary screen.
Right now I have to

- start VMWare Player (automated already)
- drag the Player window with mouse to my secondary screen
- switch to fullscreen (can be automated with VMWare settings, but would use the primary monitor without the previous step)
- open guest settings and switch display scaling (would not be necessary if guest opened on the secondary monitor to start with)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think VMware Player can do that. However, if you are using a Windows host, want to always run the VM in fullscreen mode, and don't need to edit the VM configuration, you alternatively can try running the VM with `vmware-kvm.exe` instead. `vmware-kvm.exe` is installed as part of VMware Player (and VMware Workstation). (Disclosure: I wrote vmware-kvm.)

You can run `vmware-kvm.exe --preferences` first to show a configuration dialog that allows choosing which monitor to use (and which hotkey to use to switch between the VM and the host).

Comment: Unfortunately, for some reason `vmware-kvm.exe` does not work for me - generic access violation exception. I'm on 16.2.3